# How to synchronize access to sqlite db between foreground and background process?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, synchronization

I have a service that runs in the background which can access (read and write) to sqlite database. The corresponding foreground process (main app) can also access (read and write) to sqlite database in my android application.

How can i prevent problems related to trying to access / save / read at the same time to/from sqlite db and what should be the correct way to do this?

Comment: You will have to care not only about the synchronizing service/main-thread, you will have to control, concurrency in sql-lite, witch doesn't support.

Comment: @IamStalker how about making a seperate service which is named something like CentralDbService, so every single read and write will pass through this service. Will it be tooo slow?

Comment: You can separate it to service/write | main-thread/readonly, that way you control everything in cuncurrency to db, that way you can order service to write each time you have edit data and read it by main-thread, that way every thing will stay nice and synchronized

Comment: So this is a good idea; will it be fast enough too?

Comment: Vincent has suggested a correct way to sync data in multithreaded environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 easy ways to do this, the first as ChirstopheCVB writes: Create a synchronized method. A synchronized method can only be accessed by one thread, other threads are blocked.

This is the recommended method, as it keeps all DB access related code in a single place. When you ever change the table layout of your database, you do not need to hunt through all of your code and make adjustments. You 'hide' the details from your main thread.

If you want to keep your db code in the main thread, then use semaphores. There is support for that in Java:
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

A semaphore is (simplified) a single object indicating if somebody is accessing a shared resource (e.g. your DB). Before accessing the DB, check if you are allowed and if you are, then set the object so it blocks others. Do your thing and reset the objects so others can try to access the resource.

A simple example, assume you have thread A & thread B, and a global variable canUse.

```
Init: canUse = true;

Thread A:
while (!canUse) wait;   // busy waiting, your thread is blocked
canUse = false;         // canUse was true, now we grab access.
do our thing;
canUse = true;          // Others are allowed to use the resource again.
```

Thread B looks the same.

This works, but there are 2 problems. First, you are blocking your thread because you are waiting for the resource to become available. There is a risk, because it might never become available and you have deadlock.

The second problem is more severe. Imagine you have 3 threads: A, B and C. C has grabbed the lock and both A & B are waiting. The following is possible

```
A: while (!canUse) wait;
B: while (!canUse) wait;
C: canUse = true;
A: Hooray, we can grab the resource
B: Hooray, we can grab the resource
A: canUse = false;
B: canUse = false;
```

Above example shows how important it is that checking the variable and changing it is done in an atomic way. In other words, nothing else can happen.

Fortunately, java provides you with semaphores. It is not easy to understand in the beginning, but a must to understand if you want to do what you are asking for without using synchronized methods (such methods act as semaphores for you without extra coding effort).

Comment: Thank you. Does android support named semaphores? If not, this still does not solve my main problem which is service<->app db sync.

Comment: I must admit I have not used services before in Android, but a quick look at the documentation let me believe there is no need for named semaphores.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

>A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use. 

As I understand this and the other text, the service is part of the application and will share all resources.

This is an important concept in Android, sandboxing Apps.

Comment: This is controllable. Default one is the same process, but we can create Services which run on their own process and my services need their own process :/

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks.
I'm now just brainstorming, but wouldn't transactions be working, especially with an exclusive lock?
http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html - http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html#excl_lock

Comment: Sorry, found another option: http://interprocess-android.blogspot.se/2011/11/semaphore-server.html
 Maybe a bit constructed but an option nonetheless.

Comment: This is something like what i thought, a central db processor service. So it seems like we have no other option to do this as we don't have named mutexes or semaphores here. This answer and it's comments have the most detail.