# Android: How to wait until SQLite database is available?

Tags: android

I have some actions that use a database together. In each action, how to check database is in use or not? If database is in use, i want action to wait until it is available to do something.
Thank you so much!

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172715/how-to-synchronize-access-to-sqlite-db-between-foreground-and-background-process

Comment: Why don't you execute all the database related methods in the same thread?

Comment: SQLite supports multithreaded access (see https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) is it compiled to single threaded in Andriod? Can't you use a separate SQLite installation that supports multithreaded or serialized access?